# Consistent white smoke from the exhaust

Tags: manual-transmission

I'm driving a 2011 mini (175000) and it went for service and it was serviced by a BMW mechanic. After that there was consistent white smoke every time i drive off from the 1st gear. 
what might be the problem?

Comment: How long has this been happening? Always in the morning when the engine is cold? May just be the condensation of the water vapor in the atmosphere...